# Docker jupyter/datascience-notebook won't copy to own NB_USER

Tags: docker, jupyter

I think I'm officially going mad as I can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong with my docker configuration.

What I'm trying to achieve:

- set up a Jupyter server using Jupyter/datascience-notebook as a base
- copy a bunch if start scripts into the `/home/my-user/.ipython/profile_default/startup` folder
- I don't want to use the default `jovyan` user but override to my own name

What I have:

- a `Dockerfile`
- a `docker-compose.yml`
- the startup file I'm trying to copy

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM jupyter/datascience-notebook

USER $NB_USER

ENV JUPYTER_ENABLE_LAB=yes

COPY --chown=${NB_UID}:${NB_GID} notebook-startup-scripts/00-s3fs.py .ipython/profile_default/startup
```

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3.9"
services:

  jupyter-1:
    build:
      context: ./jupyter-lab
    user: root
    working_dir: /home/my-user/work
    ports:
      - "8888:8888"
    volumes:
    environment:
      NB_USER: "my-user"
      CHOWN_HOME: "yes"
      restartable: "yes"
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    command: /usr/local/bin/start-notebook.sh --ServerApp.allow_origin="*" --ServerApp.open_browser=False --ServerApp.allow_remote_access=True --ServerApp.trust_xheaders=True --ServerApp.password=${JUPYTER_PASSWORD}
```

I start the beast using `docker compose up`.

For some reason I always end up with my `00-s3fs.py` file being synced to `/home/jovyan/.../` as opposed to `/home/my-user/.../` and it drives me nuts.
I tried all kinds of things, e.g. using

`COPY --chown=${NB_UID}:${NB_GID} notebook-startup-scripts/00-s3fs.py /home/${NB_USER}.ipython/profile_default/startup`

but nothing works :(.

Comment: The COPY command happens when the image is built -- before my-user is defined. You could make the COPY command have a destination in /home/my-user or set NB_USER to my-user at docker image build time.

Answer (score 0):

If you move `NB_USER` within your `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3.9"
services:

  jupyter-1:
    build:
      context: ./jupyter-lab
      args:
         NB_USER: "my-user"
    user: root
    working_dir: /home/my-user/work
    ports:
      - "8888:8888"
    volumes:
    environment:
      CHOWN_HOME: "yes"
      restartable: "yes"
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    command: /usr/local/bin/start-notebook.sh --ServerApp.allow_origin="*" --ServerApp.open_browser=False --ServerApp.allow_remote_access=True --ServerApp.trust_xheaders=True --ServerApp.password=${JUPYTER_PASSWORD}
```

This updates `$NB_USER` before the build process, unlike setting it within `environment`, which only sets `$NB_USER` after the image has already been build (and the file COPY already occurring).